# SharePoint Online JSOM Microsoft.Office.Server is Undefined for SetLike function

Tags: jsom, like

I'm trying to use the SetLike Function of the `Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation` library 
but I get `Server is Undefined`.

has the Microsoft.office library being deprecated or do I need to load something  before using it ?

if that happened, is there another way to use programmatically perform a like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the function didn't change, 
as SP Online doesn't load all the scripts in the first load like Sp2013, i have call the SOD.Executefunc to load the class and then execute my function on the callback.

SP.SOD.executeFunc('reputation.js', 'Microsoft.Office.Server.ReputationModel.Reputation',callback())